# sql: check the first position of unicode characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

```
Id, Name
---------
1, \n汉字\n
2, \n 张三\n
```

For example, at row 1, the first unicode charater is at index 2, and at row 2, the index is 3.

I know there is function `CHARINDEX()` can return the position, but how can I pass a mutable searching character? Something like,

```
SELECT CHARINDEX(CHAR(?>0xFF), Name) FROM tbName
```

Comment: Define "Unicode" as opposed to other characters. All characters are in the Unicode table, so what do you mean?

Comment: Perhaps it's enough for you to use patindex that excludes Latin and some other chars to find the first occurance of "unicode"